# Return selected fields only React Native / GraphQL / Amplify

Tags: react-native, graphql, aws-amplify

I have the following basic list query in GraphQL:

```
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listSomething,{filter: filter})).then(({ data: { something } }) => {
// Returns the entire object
})
```

This will return an array containing entire objects, but as I've seen on multiple GraphQL tutorials, I'd like to take advantage of the utility of only returning / plucking select fields for obvious reasons. However there isn't a lot of information out there on GraphQL + RN + Amplify. So how would I re-write this query to only return the attribute `id` for instance? Or is that something that I have to define as a resolver in the `graphql` / `queries.js` file? I'm using autogenerated queries so it sort of feels like an anti-pattern to add your own queries to that file — Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm still at an early stage of getting familiar with AWS, so please take this with a grain of salt.

Your auto generated `queries.js` will contain a listSomething query, that looks something like this:

```
export const listTodos = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListTodos(
    $filter: ModelTodoFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listTodos(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        userID
        name
        description
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

I created a new folder called `/src/customGraphQL` and created a file called `customListTodos.js`. I copied there the auto generated query, changed the query name, and removed the fields I didn't need.

```
export const customListTodos = /* GraphQL */ `
  query CustomListTodos(
    $filter: ModelTodoFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listTodos(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        name
        description
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

I only changed the query's name, but kept the inner function's name as `listTodos`, so I'm running a customised version of that query. If the original API is pushed to AWS, you can import and use the custom query:

```
import {customListTodos} from './src/customGraphQL/customListTodos';
...
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(customListTodos ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Making a custom queries file was pretty simple and I was able to limit the object to just returning the `_version`.

```
export const getUserVersion = /* GraphQL */ `
    query GetUserVersion($id: ID!) {
        getUser(id: $id) {
            _version
        }
    }
`;
```

Then in my `.js` file I could call the function this way:

```
const getUserVersionResponse = await API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(getUserVersion, { id })
);
```